CV boot been leaking grease for 3-4 months, no clicking, only vibration at speed. Grease, or Replace?
Neighbor says his car has been leaking grease from the CV boot for several months now, has been vibrating at 25 mph- 50ish, only when accelerating.
(NO clicking on turns, or otherwise.)
Would it most likely be too late to "just" pack grease into a new boot at this point?
Is it more likely that the entire axle oughtta be replaced at this point instead, due to likely damage?
Or might the new boot and grease, only, still be possible?
2007 Camry, 160k

It could be the vibration isn't the CV axle. Considering the size of it, it would take a HUGE imbalance in it to get it out of balance. All of the weight there is very central and rotates closely around itself. This sort of helps eliminate balance issues. Not completely, but it would take a bit for someone to feel it. I'd be looking more towards tires for the out of balance myself.

I'll pass that along, but he also says he already had the wheels rebalanced a couple months ago, with no real change.

If a CV joint is broken, you feel it when applying power in a tight curve. If the car can travel perfectly in curves, with no excess vibration or clicking, it is likely the CV joint is salvageable.
It should be regreased and re-booted now! Waiting can just make the problem worse. Actually, if it has been leaking for 3 months, it should have been done when it was first noticed.
If it "just" slightly leaks grease but doesn't allow too much dirt to get in, you might have been lucky. A completely broken or detached boot which allows dirt a direct way in is the worst.
It is important that both grease and boot are re-newed. Renewing only one of those won't fix it.

As an add: By stating the grease to be "re-newed", the entire joint must be excised of the old grease with new, proper grease installed prior to boot installation. If the boot/grease has been open to the elements for a period of time, the grease will have collected grit/dirt/grime and become contaminated. This contaminated grease is what will wear the CVJ out, so needs to be rid of prior to new grease being added.

Indeed, that's what I meant, complete replacement of grease, not just adding it. The old grease is dirty and the dirt needs to be removed.

I feel as though re-booting a CV joint is about the same amount of work as replacing the joint. Considering that the grease in the old joint could already be contaminated and  should be completely cleaned out and replaced, wouldn't it be worthwhile (and probably less work) for the OP to install a remanufactured CV joint instead?

@brhans - While you're not wrong about the ease of replacement, there is a huge difference in cost.
